# how to edit/update jtable cell values into database

Tags: java

am trying to edit and update jtable cells as in my code below. my problem is that a single row when updated all the other rows get the same values. i mean only one row is updated and all other a duplicated. can any one help with a good approach. thanks

```
    int count = Table_purchase.getRowCount();
    int col = Table_purchase.getColumnCount();
    String pod_id[] = new String[count];
    String po_id[] = new String[count];
    String order_qty[] = new String[count];
    String item_id[] = new String[count];
    String unit_price[] = new String[count];
    String recived_qty[] = new String[count];
    String rejected_qty[] = new String[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        po_id[i] = Table_purchase.getValueAt(i,0).toString();
        pod_id[i] = Table_purchase.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
        order_qty[i] = Table_purchase.getValueAt(i,2).toString();
        item_id[i] = Table_purchase.getValueAt(i,3).toString();
        unit_price[i] = Table_purchase.getValueAt(i,4).toString();
        recived_qty[i] = Table_purchase.getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
        rejected_qty[i] = Table_purchase.getValueAt(i,6).toString();

        try {
            String sql = "update purchase.purchase_detail set pod_id='" + pod_id[i] + "',order_qty='" + order_qty[i] + "',item_id='" + item_id[i] + "', unit_price='" + unit_price[i] + "', recived_qty='" + recived_qty[i] + "',rejected_qty='" + rejected_qty[i] + "'where  po_id= '" +  po_id[i] + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement does not contain a where-clause, hence all rows in the database table are updated for each iteration of the swing-table-rows, and in the end, all the database-rows will have the values from the last swing-table-row.

(And, use pst.setParameter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and do not mix sql into gui-code.)